# Java mimicking assembly

Tags: java, assembly

What would be the best way to write a Java program that would simulate machine code? For example, I need to create a series of instructions such as add, subtract, increment, decrement, etc. 
Let's say I'm writing the add instruction which accepts 3 parameters/registers (adding the values in the first 2 registers and storing the result in the 3rd). Is it as simple as writing a function such as:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
   int result;
   result = x + y;
   return result; }
```

I'm also open to the possibility that I'm way off base here. Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could just implement the instruction's operation with a `switch` block, and add stuff before/after for handling parameters

Comment: it depends on the operations you want to support. if you want to handle things like jump, it's going to get a lot more complicated!

Comment: What cpu do you want to emulate?  if you have a choice choose an 8 bit CPU like a Z80

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to write Java code that will be more or less 1:1 with machine instructions I'd suggest you create variables for all of the registers and define methods for most of the instructions (similar to what you suggested).  But this will not "restrict" what you can do the way real machine instructions do, since you can multiply the BX reg by the AX reg when the machine may not allow that.

Better would be to define a class that represents the machine state (ie, registers and RAM) and methods on the class for all of the instructions.  Then you couldn't multiply BX times AX unless there were a MUL_BX_AX method.  Many methods would not have parameters (because the registers are inside the "opaque" object), but some would have parms where the "real" instructions would accept an offset or whatever. (Eg, ADD_AX_IMMED(5).)

**Added:** There is the issue of branching, though, that would require some additional thought.  Java doesn't have a GOTO equivalent that would fill the role very well, so initially (until you think of something better) you might have to use standard `if`/`else` logic, et al, testing "condition codes" in the machine state class.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to simulate assembly would be to handle the raw bits and bytes and do the operations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could do that, but the big thing is how to switch on the op-codes and do all the address-field calculations.
Typically, address fields can contain literal constants, global addresses, registers, offsets relative to registers, etc.
It depends if you're simulating a simple machine or a real one.